# Symbolize External ESRI GeoJSON by Local GeoJSON

Tags: arcgis-server, geojson, arcgis-10.5

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook and attempting to symbolize an external ESRI GeoJSON service (now an output available from ArcServer 10.5) by an attribute of a local GeoJSON, and return a choropleth map.  The premise is one of combining customer data with a publicly available service.

If the two GeoJSON files are both local, I have no problem loading them with geopandas and achieving the desired result on a folium map.  However the utilization of an ESRI GeoJSON service url is proving difficult.

Anyone know of a way to do this with an external GeoJSON?

Am I missing a transformation of the ESRI GeoJSON output?

Code:

```
    import geopandas as gpd
    import folium
    import requests
    import json

    mymap = folium.map([42.65, -73.75], 
        zoom_start=7,
        tiles = 'cartodbpositron')

    geo = gpd.read_file('local.geojson')

    url = json.loads(requests.get('https://gisservices:domain/arcgis/rest/services/...f=geojson').text)

    mymap = choropleth(geo_path = url,
            fill_color='YlGn', fill_opacity=0.5, line_opacity=0.5,
            threshold_scale = [50,100,250,500,750,900],
            data = geo,  #data source I want to pull the attribute from
            key_on='feature.properties.NAME', #key field from external GeoJSON
            columns = ['COUNTY', 'Value']  #key field from local GeoJSON followed by the field I want to symbolize by                               
            )
```

Examining the data and the request I get a 200 response and what looks like a properly formatted geojson.

```
    {'crs': {'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}, 'type': 'name'},
        'features': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[-75.88982572053291,
             42.723834549294345],
             [-75.88998066913965, 42.725786369710484],
             [-75.89004324847727, 42.72657462151952],
             [-75.8900956058853, 42.72723409146341],
             ...
```

However the final portion of the code returns an error that the geo_path for the folium choropleth contains an invalid file:
"TypeError: invalid file: {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'crs':... "

Answer (score 1):

Updating my previous post I think I found an answer. In the code above I used "geo_path" when building the map choropleth. In the error output I missed an important distinction when folium creates the GeoJSON object:

```
if geo_path:
    geo_data = open(geo_path)
elif geo_str:
    geo_data = geo_str
```

Therefore I modified the code to instead use "geo_str" and was able to get a working map after export to html.  Funny thing is that the map doesn't display inside the Jupyter notebook but looks fine when I open the html file.

Working Code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import requests
import json

mymap = folium.map([42.65, -73.75], 
    zoom_start=7,
    tiles = 'cartodbpositron')

geo = gpd.read_file('local.geojson')

url = 'https://gisservices:domain/arcgis/rest/services/...f=geojson'

data = requests.get(url)
data_json = r.json()

mymap = choropleth(geo_data = data_json,
        fill_color='YlGn', fill_opacity=0.5, line_opacity=0.5,
        threshold_scale = [50,100,250,500,750,900],
        data = geo,  #data source I want to pull the attribute from
        key_on='feature.properties.NAME', #key field from external GeoJSON
        columns = ['COUNTY', 'Value']  #key field from local GeoJSON followed by the field I want to symbolize by                               
        )

mymap.save(outfile='test.html')
```

The code generates a html map that symbolizes county polygons from an Arc Server 10.5 feature service by a value contained within a local GeoJSON.

Comment: Commenting on the Folium version update, now using 0.5.0, the "geo_str" parameter has been changed and the code now uses "geo_data".